# User registration form change Username to name

Tags: users

I want to change the label of a registration form from 'Username' to name. I had used 'String overrides' module. But its not effecting. Is there any way out. please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by implementing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your custom module:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['account']['name']['#title'] = t('Name');
  }
}
```